# how to cut out a chinese words & english words mixture string in c language

Tags: c, linux, utf-8

I have a string that contains both Mandarin and English words in UTF-8:

```
char *str  = "你a好测b试";
```

If you use `strlen(str)`, it will return 14, because each Mandarin character uses three bytes, while each English character uses only one byte.

Now I want to copy the leftmost 4 characters (`"你a好测"`), and append `"..."`  at the end, to give `"你a好测..."`.

If the text were in a single-byte encoding, I could just write:

```
strncpy(buf, str, 4);
strcat(buf, "...");
```

But 4 characters in UTF-8 isn't necessarily 4 bytes.  For this example, it will be 13 bytes: three each for `你`, `好` and `测` and one for `a`.  So, for this specific case, I would need

```
strncpy(buf, str, 13);
strcat(buf, "...");
```

If I had a wrong value for the length, I could produce a broken UTF-8 stream with an incomplete character.  Obviously I want to avoid that.

How can I compute the right number of bytes to copy, corresponding to a given number of characters?

Comment: I assume you have an UTF-8 encoding, right?

Comment: Wanted to cut to "你a好测"? with a letter a?

Comment: What is your criteria for the cutting place? You want a defined number of valid codepoints (to be transformed in correctly displayable  glyphs) to the left, then the rest is three-dots-and-a-null-char? Or is something to do with the presence of non-multibyte characters? Or what?

Comment: You could convert your string to a `wchar_t` string, e.g. by using [`codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) (you tagged C++ as well as C). This would give you one character per `wchar_t`. If you want to operate on `char`-UTF-8-strings, you would have to scan each byte and check [the highest bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), to determine if a character is one, two, three or four bytes long.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to know your encoding. By the sound of it (3 byte Mandarin) your string is encoded with UTF-8.

What you need to do is convert the UTF-8 back to unicode code points (integers). You can then have an array of integers rather than bytes, so each element of the array will be 1 character, reguardless of the language.

You could also use a library of functions that already handle utf8 such as http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/utf8.c
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/utf8.h

In particular this function: `int u8_toucs(u_int32_t *dest, int sz, char *src, int srcsz);` might be very useful, it will create an array of integers, with each integer being 1 character. You can then modify the array as you see fit, then convert it back again with `int u8_toutf8(char *dest, int sz, u_int32_t *src, int srcsz);`

Comment: Third party libraries are not needed for utf8-to-ucs4 conversion, the standard library is perfectly capable of doing this.

Comment: Which functions of standard library? Isn't that part of fontconfig, not standard library?

Comment: In c++ it's std::wstring_convert, in c one can use mbstowcs (not everywhere but it works on linux well).

Comment: The C standard library can only deal with it provided that certain standard macros are defined.

Answer (score 1):

The [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) was designed to *contain characters for almost all modern languages*. In particular, it does contain Chinese.

So you just have to convert your UTF8 string to a UTF16 one to have each character using one single position. That means that you can just use a `wchar_t` array or even better a `wstring` to be allowed to use natively all string functions.

Starting with C++11, the `<codecvt>` header declares a dedicated converter `std::codecvt_utf8` to specifically convert UTF8 narrow strings to wide Unicode ones. I must admit it is not very easy to use, but it should be enough here. Code could be like:

```
char str[]  = "你a好测b试";
std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> cvt;
std::mbstate_t state = std::mbstate_t();

wchar_t wstr[sizeof(str)] = {0}; // there will be unused space at the end
const char *end;
wchar_t *wend;

auto cr = cvt.in(state, str, str+sizeof(str), end,
        wstr, wstr+sizeof(str), wend);
*wend = 0;
```

Once you have the `wstr` wide string, you can convert it to a `wstring` and use all the C++ library tools, or if you prefer C strings you can use the `ws...` counterparts of the `str...` functions.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c], not [tag:c++].

Comment: Ah, yes - I now see that in the edit history.  If only there was some more effective way to discourage askers from doing that...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend dealing with this at a higher level of abstraction: either convert to `wchar_t` or use a UTF-8 library.  But if you really want to do it at the byte level, you could count characters by skipping over the continuation bytes (which are of the form `10xxxxxx`):

```
#include <stddef.h>

size_t count_bytes_for_chars(const char *s, int n)
{
    const char *p = s;
    n += 1;  /* we're counting up to the start of the subsequent character */

    while (*p && (n -= (*p & 0xc0) != 0x80))
        ++p;
    return p-s;
}
```

Here's a demonstration of the above function:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char *str = "你a好测b试";
    char buf[50];
    int truncate_at = 4;

    size_t bytes = count_bytes_for_chars(str, truncate_at);
    strncpy(buf, str, bytes);
    strcpy(buf+bytes, "...");

    printf("'%s' truncated to %d characters is '%s'\n", str, truncate_at, buf);
}
```

Output:

```
'你a好测b试' truncated to 4 characters is '你a好测...'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure C solution:

All [UTF8 multibyte characters will be made from `char`-s with the most-significant-bit set to 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) with the first bits of their first character indicating how many characters makes a codepoint.

The question is ambiguous in regards to the criterion used in cutting; either:

1. a fixed number of codepoints followed by three dots, this wil require a variable size output buffer
2. a fixed size output buffer, which will impose "whatever you can fit inside"

Both the solutions will require a helper function telling how many chars make the next codepoint:

```
// Note: the function does NOT fully validate a
// UTF8 sequence, only looks at the first char in it
int codePointLen(const char* c) {
  if(NULL==c) return -1;
  if( (*c & 0xF8)==0xF0 ) return 4; // 4 ones and one 0 
  if( (*c & 0xF0)==0xE0 ) return 3; // 3 ones and one 0
  if( (*c & 0xE0)==0xC0 ) return 2; // 2 ones and one 0
  if( (*c & 0x7F)==*c   ) return 1; // no ones on msb
  return -2; // invalid UTF8 starting character
}
```

So, solution for the criterion 1 (fixed number of code points, variable output buff size) - does not append `...` to the destination, but you can ask "how many chars I need" upfront and if it is longer than you can afford, reserve yourself the extra space.

```
// returns the number of chars used from the output
// If not enough space or the dest is null, does nothing
// and returns the lenght required for the output buffer
// Returns negative val if the source in not a valid UTF8
int copyFirstCodepoints(
   int codepointsCount, const char* src,
   char* dest, int destSize
) {
  if(NULL==src) {
    return -1;
  }
  // do a cold run to see if size of the output buffer can fit
  // as many codepoints as required
  const char* walker=src;
  for(int cnvCount=0; cnvCount<codepointsCount; cnvCount++) {
    int chCount=codePointLen(walker);
    if(chCount<0) {
      return chCount; // err
    }
    walker+=chCount;
  }
  if(walker-src < destSize && NULL!=dest) {
    // enough space at destination
    strncpy(src, dest, walker-src);
  }
  // else do nothing
  return walker-src;
}
```

Second criterion (limited buffer size): just use the first one with the number of codepoints returned by this one

```
// return negative if UTF encoding error
int howManyCodepointICanFitInOutputBufferOfLen(const char* src, int maxBufflen) {
  if(NULL==src) {
    return -1;
  }
  int ret=0;
  for(const char* walker=src; *walker && ret<maxBufflen; ret++) {
     int advance=codePointLen(walker);
     if(advance<0) {
       return src-walker; // err because negative, but indicating the err pos
     }
     // look on all the chars between walker and walker+advance
     // if any is 0, we have a premature end of the source
     while(advance>0) {
       if(0==*(++walker)) {
         return src-walker; // err because negative, but indicating the err pos
       }
       advance--;
     } // walker is set on the correct position for the next attempt
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: He wanted to cut to "你a好测" with a letter a

Comment: no, i want to limit a string's size,which string contains chinese and english words,  the question is how to find the right postion to avoid chinese word become garbled. i find the right way.

Comment: @iverhan to limit which string?

Comment: @TobySpeight "or use an existing library". Personally, I prefer [Bjoern Hoehrmann UTF8 decoder](http://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/): dam' it's fast. However, in this case, there seems to be a barrier for the OP caused by [ZPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_of_proximal_development) - perhaps it's better to show some inner works, however imperfect, to kick them further.

Comment: @adrian, that's a good link; thanks for posting that.  I've expanded my suggestion into an actual answer (despite having said I'd leave it as an exercise) as I think it might be instructive - and it avoids actually decoding the string just to count it.

Comment: @TobySpeight which link? The UTF8 decoder or the Zone of Proximal Development one? (based on your reaction, I assume is the latter, I'm not sure, but still curious)

Comment: @adrian, I meant the first one - it's great to see code with such a clear "how it works" as well as "how to use".  The second link is worthwhile, but it was the first that really impressed.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks.

Comment: "char-s with the most-significant-bit set to 1" Except when `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static char *CutStringLength(char *lpszData, int nMaxLen)
{
    if (NULL == lpszData || 0 >= nMaxLen)
    {
            return "";
    }
    int len = strlen(lpszData);
    if(len <= nMaxLen)
    {
            return lpszData;
    }
    char strTemp[1024] = {0};
    strcpy(strTemp, lpszData);
    char *p = strTemp;
    p = p + (nMaxLen-1);

    if ((unsigned char)(*p) < 0xA0)
    {
        *(++p) = '\0';  // if the last byte is Mandarin character
    }
    else if ((unsigned char)(*(--p)) < 0xA0)
    {
        *(++p) = '\0';  // if the last but one byte is Mandarin character
    }
    else if ((unsigned char)(*(--p)) < 0xA0)
    {
        *(++p) = '\0';  // if the last but two byte is Mandarin character
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        p = strTemp;
        while(*p != '\0' && i+2 <= nMaxLen)
        {
           if((unsigned char)(*p++) >= 0xA0 && (unsigned char)(*p) >= 0xA0)
           {
               p++;
               i++;
           }
           i++;
       }
       *p = '\0';
    }
    printf("str = %s\n",strTemp);
    return strTemp;
 }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.